# unexpected output of paste(data.frame(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31"))))

Tags: r

```
#eg1:
paste(data.frame(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31"))))
[1]"1"
#eg2:
paste(data.table(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31"))))
[1]"2019-10-12"
#eg3:
paste(data.frame(a=as.Date("2019-12-31")))
[1] 18261
```

**my expected is like eg2, but i don't want use data.table**

I have only one  question: how to fix this issue, both eg2 and eg3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a character into a data.frame, it is turned into a factor. When you print a factor, it would seem data.table and data.frame are coerced differently. For your particular case, I was able to get around it by unlisting and converting to character before using paste.

```
> paste(as.character(unlist(data.frame(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31"))))))
[1] "2019-12-31"
```

Alternatively, you could avoid this by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and avoid the factor conversion.

```
> paste(data.frame(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
[1] "2019-12-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are trying to use `paste()` if what you want to do is *view* what is contained inside the data frame.  Instead, just enter the variable name of the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=as.character(as.Date("2019-12-31")))
df

           a
1 2019-12-31
```

Comment: what cause this happen? I want to know, because of business needs

Comment: Well obviously `paste` handles data frame and data tables differently.  But why does this matter to you?